# In Java why does this return a negative number when searching the array with binary search?

Tags: java, arrays, search, sorting, binary

I am a beginner in Java and is learning to use array. I understand that when using the binary search method of Array, it will return a negative number if the entry is not found. However, in the following code, I am getting a negative number returned for 9, 10, and 11.

I am wondering if anyone could help point out what I am doing wrong? thanks!

```
   String [] oneToSixteen = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"};

   System.out.println("Searching for 7: "+ Arrays.binarySearch(oneToSixteen, "7"));
   System.out.println("Searching for 8: "+ Arrays.binarySearch(oneToSixteen, "8"));
   System.out.println("Searching for 9: "+ Arrays.binarySearch(oneToSixteen, "9"));
   System.out.println("Searching for 10: "+ Arrays.binarySearch(oneToSixteen, "10"));
   System.out.println("Searching for 11: "+ Arrays.binarySearch(oneToSixteen, "11"));
```

The output i get are:

```
Searching for 7: 6
Searching for 8: 7
Searching for 9: -17
Searching for 10: -2
Searching for 11: -2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The string array is not sorted (in which case the return value of binarySearch is undefined).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because your array is an an array of `String` and not `int` and **it is not sorted**.

The documentation clearly states that the array being searched must be sorted and if it isn't the results are undefined.

To sort the array you can use the [sort method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) of the Arrays class.

Comment: The "not sorted" point is fair - but what's the reason for your comment about the *array type*?  He's searching by `String`, and `String` is `Comparable`.

Comment: @11684: Arrays.sort would do the trick... although of course that would change all the results.

Comment: @GregKopff: I suspect the point is that they're not sorted *because* they're strings (which compare according to lexicographical order); the same values *as integers* are obviously appropriately sorted already.

Comment: @11684: Exactly - that's the lexicographic order of those strings.

Comment: @GregKopff: if it wouold have been a `int` array, then 1,2,3,4,..12 is implicitly sorted.. nto for `String`. for String, sorted is using ascii value.

Comment: @JonSkeet: yes, I suppose when I read it I picked up on the fact that if you sorted it, then the code would work.  Or *alternately*, you could change the type to `int`.  The wording, I think, makes out that you need to do both - sort it and change it to int - whereas you only need to do one (because the ints are already sorted).  I think it would be better if it pointed out that the strings are not currently in lexicographical order, and that's why they need to be sorted.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help. I have now got the code to work, it is indeed as you all mentioned. After sorting the array, the code works flawlessly. Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

The negative refers the component-1 where the String would be found / inserted int your array, and comes up because your array not being sorted.  The element is not being found.
so  for your array 
"9" being -17 that it will be inserted into component 16
"10" would be inserted into component 1
"11" would be inserted into component 1

Type of Array doesn't matter as the Arrays methods have been overloaded.

sort by Using

```
Arrays.sort(oneToSixteen);
```

then use your binarySearch()

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that to make `Array.binarySearch(array, key)` method work correctly the source array **must be sorted** before. If the source array is not sorted, the result will be undefined. From your question, the source array is not sorted. To sort array in natural order you use the util method `Arrays.sort(array)`. You can also provide an additional comparator to control the sort order `Arrays.sort(array, comparator)`.

Example:

```
// sort in natural order (ascending)
Arrays.sort(oneToSixteen);

// sort descending using comparator
Arrays.sort(oneToSixteen, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
});
```